# How to make height more than wrap_content in Android?

Tags: android, listview, height

I have a ListView where each objects in the list has the parameter:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

However, this makes the objects hard to press. I don't want to increase the font size to achieve this. Instead, can I add a buffer to wrap_content?

I'd like to implement something like:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content" + 10dp
```

How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add some margin or padding to your views. Alternatively, embed a `<View>` element with fixed 10dip height.

Answer (score 4):

you can use padding property so its automatically set height & width what you want...

```
android:padding="10dip"
```

Answer (score 2):

you would have to do that programmatically most likely. Because that method wont work.

Not exact coding but along the lines:

```
View what_i_want_to_resize = (View)findViewById(R.id.myview);
View view_with_the_size = (View)findViewById(R.id.sizeview);

what_i_want_to_resize.setMinimumHeight(view_with_the_size.getMeasuredHeight() + 10);
```

Something along those lines. It is impossible to do it with XML.

You can also add padding to it.

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

That will make a padding or cushion between the views.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `android:layout_margin="10dip"` or padding.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `android:layout_height="50dp"` or any figure directly